# message queue storage limit on a single queue doesn't work?

Tags: c#, msmq

[Send()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh1ct41.aspx) doesn't throw exception when the queue is full.

I have two private message queue, say queue and queue1, i set message storage of queue1 to a small amount say 5120 kb, in my program i send message to both queue and queue1, when queue1 is full while the global queue is not full, the Send() method on queue1 doesn't throw exception, why is this? i was expecting the send() method on queue1 throw exception so i know it is full.

[image: queue message storage]

Comment: Please clarify if sender and queue are on the same or different machines

Answer (score 1):

I think this is by design:

from [MSMQ FAQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/9/FC9989A2-DA75-4D96-B654-4BD29CF6AEE1/MSMQ_faq_updated.doc):

> MQSendMessage() always succeeds even when it is obvious that the
>   message cannot be sent. Why? The success of MQSendMessage() does not
>   guarantee the delivery of the message to its ultimate destination. The
>   success of MQSendMessage() merely means that the local MSMQ service
>   successfully accepted the message and it will process it as soon as
>   possible. It doesn't imply any guarantee to deliver the message to its
>   destination queue. There are many reasons for failures to deliver a
>   message. For example:
>
> - You attempt to send a nontransactional message to a transaction    queue.
> - You send a message to a queue that has exceeded its quota.
> - You send a message to a queue which does not grant  you the send    permission.
> - You send a message to a computer which does   not exist, using the    DIRECT format name.
>
> MQSendMessage() will succeed in all these cases, by design. It is the
>   destination computer which reject such messages. Or the message will
>   wait in an outgoing queue until it expires.

Comment: If the destination is remote. Send will create the message in the local outgoing queue which can know nothing of any quota limits. If the destination is local then the Send should try and create a message directly in the local queue and fail.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell, if the queue is local, and i set the quota limits on the single queue, when the queue is is full, Send() still succeed without exception.